# How to stop Array from constantly re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have an image array where I am updating each value when I click on a button in react and pick an image. However the array is constantly rerendering when I only want it to when I pick an image.
Here is my code:

```
   function OnboardingUploadPhotos() {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [permissionStatus, setPermissionStatus] = useState('');
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [fileArray, setFileArray] = useState<string[]>(['', '', '', '', '', '', '']);

  const setPermissions = useCallback(val => {
    setPermissionStatus(val);
  }, [setPermissionStatus]);

  const setIsModalVisible = useCallback(val => {
    setModalVisible(val);
  }, [setModalVisible]);

  async function fetchAssets() {
    const recentCameraRoll = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({first: 11});
    setFiles(recentCameraRoll.assets.slice(1).map(file => file.uri));
  }

  function replaceFileState(file: string, index: number) {
    let f = [...fileArray];
    f[index] = file;
    setFileArray(f);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAssets();
  }, [fetchAssets]);

  return (
      <View>
        {permissionStatus ?
            <Modal style={styles.bottomModalView} isVisible={modalVisible} backdropOpacity={0}
                   onBackdropPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
              <View style={styles.modal}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Text style={{
                    borderBottomWidth: 1,
                    borderBottomColor: '#FFF',
                    color: '#FFF',
                    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
                    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    paddingTop: 40
                  }}>All photos</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <ScrollView horizontal={true} scrollEnabled={true}
                            contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                  {files.map((file, index) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={index} onPress={() => replaceFileState(file, index)}>
                          <Image
                              key={file}
                              style={{width: 100, height: 100, marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10, borderRadius: 4}}
                              source={{uri: file}}
                          />
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    );
                  })}
                </ScrollView>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 22, color: '#FFF', marginLeft: 20, marginBottom: 20}}>Your photos</Text>
              </View>
            </Modal> :
            null
        }
        <Text>Upload your photos</Text>
        <View style={{flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap", justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}>
          {fileArray.slice(0,6).map((image, index) => {
            console.log(fileArray)
            return (
                image != '' ?
                    <Image
                        key={image}
                        style={{width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 100}}
                        source={{uri: image}}
                    /> :
                    <OnboardingPhoto key={index} setStatus={setPermissions} setModal={setIsModalVisible}/>
            )
          })}
        </View>
      </View>
  );
}
```

It is a modal that has all the users latest images and on click of each image it replaces the empty placeholder image with the users image on the screen. However it constantly rerenders. Id say put it in a `useEffect` but I do not know where! Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to define a `key` property on the `TouchableWithoutFeedback` component.

See the guidelines here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Would this be the same for the TouchableOpacity as it extends TouchableWithoutFeedback's props?

Comment: Also this works and stops the photos rerendering but I have a console.log(fileArray) that still rerenders everytime?

Comment: This is how React works. Where is your console.log statement placed? React will call your component many times, but it won't necessarily result in a new render. "Key" allows React to see if something changed.

Comment: Ah, yes its just outside my jsx return function. I never knew what Key really did! Thankyou!

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer solved your question, remember to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi Mathias, unfortunately my array is still making tonnes of calls and its slowing down my app. Your key idea helped to get my array working as I wanted it to. But its still broke and Im not sure why. Ive given my full code - maybe you can see whats going wrong?

Comment: You set your Image element's key property to the image itself. That won't work. Use index instead. In fact, don't do that either - use something like `image-${index}` instead, so that your keys won't collide with the TouchableWithoutFeedback keys. All keys must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are ment to be used inside Function Components, that's maybe one of the reasons.

Comment: I solved my initial problem but instead my work now constantly rerenders! Any ideas?